# Handling large numbers of objects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, object

We need to migrate some data to a new system and the only way to do it is to use the provided webservices. Can someone provide some advice on how to do this? Should i preload eg. 1000 objects in a list then clear it to avoid out of memory exception?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: Why the un-explained down vote?  If you vote something down have the decency to explain why, if nothing else, to help improve the question and answer for people who stumble upon it later.

Comment: What is the nature of the objects? Are they large or small?

Comment: @Steve They can be quite large and deep.

Comment: Can you process those objects as you receive them from the webservice? Either serializing them to local file, or some table in some database? This way you'd have them locally first, and then it may be easier to proceed afterwards.

Comment: @Sergei It's the other way around. I'm getting the data from our old system db and importing them via webservices to the new system.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you have got for the data migration is a web service; yes you will have to load them all and do necessary processing/migration (doing batch wise is better if your web service supports).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support batch loads.

Comment: @ sysboard : How many records you have to migrate? If they are not big data chunks it won't be that difficult to load them all and do migration. Especially if it is a one time migration. I cannot see any other way with your constraints.

Comment: Well it depends. The booking records would probably be around 5 mio.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the Migration Process in two
1)Export
  Load all your data in a XML File by defining a xml schema which will be suitable for your WebService input.
2)Import get the Data from the XML use your webservice based upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the Webservice for every single Object? Or is it neccessary to send all of them at once?
If you can send single Objects, you can send the Object to the Webservice and afterwards Dispose it.
The Problem with the real big XML are that the parsers can't read them to infinite. If you really have to send all Items at once please consider using [XOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-binary_Optimized_Packaging) for the transport.

But I think the only soultion is a single processing of the objects (or a huge ammount of memory;-)